# java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I get the error **java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted ResultSet** to run a query against an Oracle database. The connection is via a connection pool defined in Websphere. The code executed is as follows:

```java
if (rs! = null) (
    while (rs.next ()) (
        count = rs.getInt (1);
    )
)
```

I note that the resultset contains data (rs.next ())

Thanks

Comment: Has the statement or connection be closed while reading the result set?

Comment: @Arne: that would rather have thrown a `SQLException: ResultSet is closed`.

Comment: In the future, add the stacktrace and point the line. Seeing the accepted answer the line where it was thrown was **absolutely not** in the code which you posted in your question. You should practice more with interpreting stacktraces. I deleted my answer.

Comment: Yup, was absolutely not in the code because I figured it :-) Always i've seen this error was caused for same issue.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've seen this error while trying to access a column value after processing the resultset.

```
if (rs != null) {
  while (rs.next()) {
    count = rs.getInt(1);
  }
  count = rs.getInt(1); //this will throw Exhausted resultset
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Simple and Clear, Thanks

Comment: will it create the same exception for other databases(like mysql, sql server etc)?

Comment: I don't know. Probably yes. I supose it depends on database vendor :-)

Comment: white space between '! ='  is not allowed :)

Comment: Thanks. Changed my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if (rs != null && rs.first()) {
    do {
        count = rs.getInt(1);
    } while (rs.next());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you reset the result set to the top, using `rs.absolute(1)` you won't get exhaused result set.

```
while (rs.next) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
rs.absolute(1);
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
```

You can also use rs.first() instead of rs.absolute(1), it does the same.

Answer (score 2):

When there is no records returned from Database for a particular condition and When I tried to access the rs.getString(1);  I got this error "exhausted resultset".

**Before the issue, my code was:**

```
rs.next();
sNr= rs.getString(1);
```

**After the fix:**

```
while (rs.next()) {
    sNr = rs.getString(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception occurs when the ResultSet is used outside of the while loop. Please keep all processing related to the ResultSet inside the While loop.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs typically when the stmt is reused butexpecting a different ResultSet, try creting a new stmt and executeQuery. It fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

**Problem behind the error:** If you are trying to access Oracle database you will not able to access inserted data until the transaction has been successful and to complete the transaction you have to fire a `commit` query after inserting the data into the table. Because Oracle database is not on auto commit mode by default.

**Solution:**

Go to SQL PLUS and follow the following queries..

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Nov 28 15:29:43 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: scott
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> desc empdetails;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ENO                                                NUMBER(38)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(20)
 SAL                                                FLOAT(126)

SQL> insert into empdetails values(1010,'John',45000.00);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sur that res.getInt(1) is not null.
If it can be null, use **Integer count = null;** and not int count =0;

```
Integer count = null;
    if (rs! = null) (
                    while (rs.next ()) (
                        count = rs.getInt (1);
                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are using the resultSet before the resultSet.next() method.

To get the count the just use this:

while (rs.next ())
`{
   count = rs.getInt (1);
 }

You will get your result.