# java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, resultset, sqlexception, executequery

I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.getOracleObject(ScrollableResultSet.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.getFloat(ScrollableResultSet.java:828)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getFloat(OracleResultSet.java:1552)
    at website.web.InboxReader.NormalizeImp(InboxReader.java:625)
    at website.web.InboxReader.accessGmail(InboxReader.java:122)
    at website.web.InboxReader.main(InboxReader.java:51)
```

after these lines:

```
    ResultSet parentMessage = parentstmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(IMPORTANCE) AS IMPAVG FROM MAIL");
    avgsum = parentMessage.getFloat("IMPAVG");
```

Am I not doing the above correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502005/java-sql-sqlexception-exhausted-resultset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try calling

```
parentMessage.next();
```

before trying to access SQL