# Where to close result set

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting result set is already closed where i am passing resultset into other method.where should i closed result set.

```
public void mainTest(){

ResultSet rs= pstmt.executeQuery(query);

List list = populateRS(rs);

if(rs!=null)rs.close();
}

public List populateRS(ResultSet rs){

//work with result set
if(rs!=null)rs.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use a `try-finally` block to close the `ResultSet` even if `populateRS` (or something else) throws an exception:

```
ResultSet rs;
try {
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery(query);
    List list = populateRS(rs);
} finally {
    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So i should close the result set in mainTest not in populateRS.is it? public void mainTest(){ ResultSet rs= pstmt.executeQuery(query); List list = populateRS(rs); if(rs!=null)rs.close(); } public List populateRS(ResultSet rs){ //work with result set }

Comment: Yes, I think it is always clearer (and less error-prone) to create and close a `ResultSet` in one method, and let any other method you call just deal with handling the results themselves (without having to worry about opening, closing, checking if it's already open, ...).

Comment: @Jaque I think that is probably a different problem with your `populateRS` method. See similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502005/java-sql-sqlexception-exhausted-resultset) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495835/sqlexception-exhausted-resultset).

Answer (score 5):

Close in the same method you open in if at all possible.  Consistently doing this makes it easy for code-reviewers and maintainers to easily triage resources into (obviously freed, obviously problematic, and needs more attention).

A few other notes:

1. Use `try (...)` or do the closing in `finally` so the resource is closed even when the code using it fails with an exception.
2. Use the [`@WillClose` and `@WillNotClose`](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/11/jsr-305-annotations.html#io) annotations as appropriate so that IDEs and tools like findbugs can point out problems.

---

```
public void mainTest(){
  List<?> list;
  try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    list = populateRS(rs);
  }
  // work with list
}

public List<?> populateRS(@WillNotClose ResultSet rs){
  //work with result set
}
```

or if you're stuck with older Java:

```
public void mainTest(){
  List<?> list;
  ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(query);
  try {
    list = populateRS(rs);
  } finally {
    if(rs!=null)rs.close();
  }
  // work with list
}
```

Comment: Where did the `@WillNotClose` annotation come from? Is that part of the JDK or some other library?

Comment: @andersschuller JSR-305

Comment: @andersschuller, Please see the link I added.

Comment: @Jaque, check that there are more rows before getting the next row.

Comment: And from Java 7 on, use try with autoclose

Answer (score 3):

Use the new **[try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)** which would automatically close the ResultSet whether an exception occurs or not because it implements **[AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)**.

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

```
public void mainTest()
{
  try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(query)) { 
     List list = populateRS(rs);
  } catch (SQLException ex) {

  }
}

public List populateRS(ResultSet rs){
    // work with result set
}
```

Comment: Only from Java 7 on.

Answer (score 2):

It is good to close where you are opening .
**It is good programming practise to close all resouces in *finally* block**

```
       public void mainTest()
       {
         ResultSet rs = null;
         try{ 
              rs= pstmt.executeQuery(query);
             List list = populateRS(rs);
          }finally{
               try {
                 rs.close();
               } catch (SQLException ex) {

               }
          }
      }

     public List populateRS(ResultSet rs){

        //work with result set

    }
```

according to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

> Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

Close things near where you open them. In this case that would be in the mainTest method after you call populateRS. If a method doesn't open something, it shouldn't close it.

Comment: So i should close the result set in mainTest not in populateRS.is it?

public void mainTest(){

ResultSet rs= pstmt.executeQuery(query);

List list = populateRS(rs);

if(rs!=null)rs.close();
}

public List populateRS(ResultSet rs){

//work with result set

}

Comment: I think it is often appropriate for methods to close things that other pass to it, as long as the contract is clear. It is often done with streams.

Comment: @Jaque: yes. you can put the rs.close in a finally block or use try-with-resources.

Comment: @Colin: there can be exceptions, but this is an easy case. like Dave Newton said, this is basic Separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the `ResultSet` in the `mainTest` method to segregate `populateRS` method's participation in the lifecycle of the `ResultSet`.

You should have a `finally` block in which you should close the `ResultSet`. This practice gives you a guarantee that the `ResultSet` is closed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: I disagree; the responsibility of populateRS should be to work w/ the result set, not to participate in its lifecycle. Basic separation of concerns.