# Exception resultset exhausted is occuring again and again

Tags: java, sql, resultset

resultset exhausted exception is occuring again and again ,i have checked all possibilities. my tables contain similar data but it is occuring.. i m pasting my code here.. please guide me

```
  ArrayList<Duty> myList = new ArrayList<Duty>();
    try {

        String query = "select * from CBMS.DUTIES";
        ResultSet r = con.statement.executeQuery(query);

        while (r.next()) {
            Centre c = null;
            Teacher t = null;
            query = "select * from CBMS.center";
            ResultSet r1 = con.statement.executeQuery(query);

            while (r1.next()) {

                if (r.getInt(2) == r1.getInt(1)) {
                    c = new Centre(r1.getString(3), r1.getInt(1), r1.getString(2));
                    break;
                }
            }

            query = "select * from CBMS.teacher";
            ResultSet r7 = con.statement.executeQuery(query);
            while (r7.next()) {
                System.out.println(r7.getString(1));
                if (r.getInt(3) == r7.getInt(2)) {
                    t = new Teacher(r7.getString(1), r7.getInt(2), r7.getString(3), r7.getString(4), r7.getString(5));

                    break;
                }
            }


            Duty d = new Duty(c, t, r.getString(4), r.getInt(1));
            myList.add(d);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return myList;
```

Comment: *"i have checked all possibilities"*  One possibility works, so obviously you haven't.  BTW - Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: All possibilities mean that i have tried my best but no gain

Comment: Andrew Thompson please answer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with regular results sets it is not possible to go back and forth as you do in your code. So when you run `r.next()` you cannot go to the previous value (and you do that several times).  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3502545/2568511). You should refactor your code and put the values into variables that you can reuse.