# JAVA EXHAUSTED RESULTSET above certain rows

Tags: java

We are using a oracle sql statement to capture the records in a rsultset , we have observed that whenever the rowlimit is <=70 , the code is working fine and the insert proc is getting called properly after clicking the submit button.

Whenever the rowcount >70 , after clicking the submit button blank page is appearing and found that insert proc is not getting called , error Result set exhausted

We have checked the connection time pull out it is fine

We have checked if the resultset is closed properly or not that is also fine

We are using JBOSS server, need your help how we can increase the limit so that it can accpet >70 rows also .

Comment: show us the code please

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502005/java-sql-sqlexception-exhausted-resultset