# Exhausted Resultset in java jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

```
pst=con.prepareStatement("Select * from stu_extra where stu_id like 'Kul7Dub514'");
rs=pst.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
    stclasscombo.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(2));
    for(int i=3;i<10;i++)
        System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
    if(rs.getString(10).equals("PCM"))
    {
        PCM.setSelected(true);
    }
    else if(rs.getString(10).equals("PCB"))
    {
        PCB.setSelected(true);
    }
    else  if(rs.getString(10).equals("PCMB"))
    {
        PCMB.setSelected(true);
    }
    if(rs.getString(11).equals("true"))
    {
        NEET.setSelected(true);
    }
    if(rs.getString(12).equals("true"))
    {
        IPCC.setSelected(true);
    }
    act_fee.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(13)));
    conc.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(14)));
    tot_fee.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(15)));
    no_instl.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(16)));
}
```

the code is returning with an exhausted result set error
the first values is obtained 
i.e at column 2 
but the later values are not retrieved 
Please Help...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502005/java-sql-sqlexception-exhausted-resultset

Comment: which line ?? stack trace please.

Comment: i got the solution......i created a new prepared statement and result set..by the way the problem was at line 6