# Exhausted Resultset exception in Java

Tags: java, oracle11g

Can someone please tell me how to get rid of the Exhausted Resultset exception. I have tried looking at other questions posted on this site but nothing seems to be helping. I am getting the error even after using the .next() method. Btw, the sql code does return rows, and it is not an empty set.
This is my code:

```
package jdbcManabu;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TwoTables
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection tsunagu = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "hr", "hr");  
            Statement gyo = tsunagu.createStatement(); 
            String sql1 =
                    "SELECT e1.salary, e2.salary FROM employees e1 INNER JOIN employees e2 ON e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id WHERE e1.salary > 20000";

            ResultSet set1 = gyo.executeQuery(sql1);
            ResultSetMetaData  meta1 = set1.getMetaData(); 

            for(int i=1; i <= meta1.getColumnCount(); i++)
                System.out.print(meta1.getColumnName(i) + "=" + meta1.getColumnTypeName(i));

            int clmns = meta1.getColumnCount();
            while(set1.next());
            {
                for(int i = 1; i <= clmns; i++)
                {
                  System.out.print( set1.getInt(i) + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }


            tsunagu.close();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502005/java-sql-sqlexception-exhausted-resultset)

Comment: `while(set1.next());` <-- remove the semicolon here

Comment: Voted to close as typo rather than duplicate due to the semicolon after the `while`.

Comment: Thanks for solving it. Not noticing the semicolon was such an embarrassing thing to do.